# update user list in group: UPDATE or DELETE + INSERT

Tags: mysql

Group 8 contains users: 1, 2, 3

```
user_id | group_id
------------------
    1   |    8
------------------
    2   |    8
------------------
    3   |    8
------------------
```

Need to update user list for group 8.

So group 8 should contain users: 1, 5, 7

```
user_id | group_id
------------------
    1   |    8
------------------
    5   |    8
------------------
    7   |    8
------------------
```

For this particular case and table structure, what is the best way to do it?

"UPDATE" is updating an existing record(s) in a table.
So I guess "UPDATE" will NOT work for me, right?

Do I have to delete (with "DELETE") all users from group 8 and insert (with "INSERT INTO") a new updated list of users?

EDIT:
user list before update and user list after update is arbitrary and dynamic, may not be exactly like in my example.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to update a primary key even if the database allows it. The effect on the child table(s) (if any) should be studied carefully. Also, before you delete the rows, check the effect on child tables as this may cause cascade deletes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, delete and insert is the way to go. You remove user 2 and 3, then you add user 5 and 7. You do not need to touch user 1.

An update is not good, because conceptually your are removing a user from the group and you join another one. You're not transforming one user into an other.